# No match for operator>> issue

Tags: c++, unix

I am running this program in a unix terminal but when I try to compile it gives a huge list of issues however i believe the issue is the part saying no match for operator>>. I realize the program is missing a lot it isn't near complete I would like to be able to compile it before I go much further though. I have no idea what is causing this error any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ui = 0 ;
    vector<string> in;
    string temp = "0";
    int vsize = 0;

    while(ui != 5)
    {
            cout << "1.     Read" << endl;
            cout << "2.     Print" << endl;
            cout << "3.     Sort" << endl;
            cout << "4.     Search" << endl;
            cout << "5.     Quit" << endl;
            std::cin >> ui >> std::endl;

            if(ui = 1)
            {
                    while(temp  != "q")
                    {
                            std::cout << "Enter the next element (Enter 'q' to stop):" << std::endl;
                            std::cin >> temp >>  std::endl;
                            in.pushback(temp);
                            vsize++;
                    }
            }

            if(ui = 2)
            {
                    std::cout << "Sequence: ";
                    for (int i = 0; i < vsize; i++)
                    {
                            cout << in[i];
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
            }

            if(ui = 3)
            {
            }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `std::cin >> temp >>  std::endl;` Are you trying to read data into `endl`?

Comment: Please provide the relevant info when you post. That includes *complete error message*.

Comment: *"...I would like to be able to compile it before I go much further..."* Good instinct; you should compile it without warnings before you go *any* further. You might even retreat to a simpler version until you get this problem sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

You know you are doing assignments in your if-statements? Equality is written `==` in C++. Also, why the vsize? A vector has its own method for getting the size, `in.size()` would give you that.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to be able to compile it before I go much further...* Nice!

But you should **read** the error and warning messages, they often help to understand the problem and the way to fix it (following uses CLang output):

```
ess.cpp:21:31: error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved;
  did you mean to call it?
        std::cin >> ui >> std::endl;
```

You are trying to extract something into `std::endl` which is non sense. Just write `std::cin >> ui;`

```
ess.cpp:23:19: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
  parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        if(ui = 1)
```

`ui = 1` is an assignment. The equality test should be `if (ui == 1)`

```
ess.cpp:29:32: error: no member named 'pushback' in
  'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char,
  std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
  std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char,
  std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >'; did you
  mean 'push_back'?
                        in.pushback(temp);
```

... and I assume too that you did mean `in.push_back(temp);`

I only took once example for each error, you should be able to fix duplicates :-)